# Why does Lua loadstring() not work on the demo site?

Tags: lua

I am trying to test out the Lua loadstring function.

This example is taken direction from the Lua documentation:

```
f = loadstring("i = i + 1")
```

However, when I try to run it at:

https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo

I get the following error:

```
input:1: attempt to call a nil value (global 'loadstring')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`loadstring`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-loadstring) is not available in Lua past version 5.1. The demo you linked is running Lua 5.3. You can prove this by running the program `print(_VERSION)`.

In Lua 5.2 an later your code should use [`load`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-load), here is an example program you can run that loads a chunk from a string:

```
local f = load("return 2 + 2")
print(f())
```

Answer (score 1):

It is Lua 5.4 and load is there.
Look...

```
tdump=[[for k,v in pairs(_G) do print(k,v) end]]
load(tdump)()
```

I think the Lua 5.4 CGI is cutted down of functions because of security reasons.
Look...

```
tdump=[[for k,v in pairs(_G.io) do print(k,v) end]]
load(tdump)()
```

...there is only: `write()`